# Best tree structure for Multi-dimensional data

Tags: data-structures, tree, multidimensional-array

To organize multi-dimensional data,
What is the most **useful** and **efficient tree** data structure?
(eg, K-D-B tree, region quadtree, R-tree)

I want to know **best search time** and **best space utilization** tree structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It highly depends on how your data is distributed in the space and how you want to search for it (what are the criteria you query for?).

It is very easy to find the right quad-tree bin given a location in space, on the other hand it introduces more overhead than a well-shaped kd-tree. There is a reason why all of these techniques are still in use.

Specify the problem you want to solve with the data structure.

Answer (score 1):

Different data structures, including trees and information about them and source code of their implementation is found at https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~ece250/Algorithms/

Furthermore, runtime information and asymptotic analysis on different types of tree structures is found under section 4 at https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~ece250/Lectures/Slides/

These are very useful and reliable and this way you can choose the best structure depending on your specific needs/ data

I hope this helps!